# CRM Dynamics Update Option Set Values with data from another sql table

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

Hi I am a bit stuck with regards to automatically updating a CRM Option Set value with data from another external SQL table, I have a requirement to update CRM option sets when a value in an external table is updates as a new value, I know that updating the MSCRM SQL db is not supported and I was wondering what would be a different way to do it in an automated way. Your help will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can update specific values in a global or local option set by using [`UpdateOptionValueRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.updateoptionvaluerequest%28v=crm.6%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[MSDN has an example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509070(v=crm.6).aspx) of how to use this request:

```cs
// In order to change labels on option set values (or delete) option set
// values, you must use UpdateOptionValueRequest 
// (or DeleteOptionValueRequest).
UpdateOptionValueRequest updateOptionValueRequest =
    new UpdateOptionValueRequest
    {
        OptionSetName = _globalOptionSetName,
        // Update the second option value.
        Value = optionList[1].Value.Value,
        Label = new Label("Updated Option 1", _languageCode)
    };

_serviceProxy.Execute(updateOptionValueRequest);

//Publish the OptionSet
PublishXmlRequest pxReq3 = new PublishXmlRequest { ParameterXml = String.Format("<importexportxml><optionsets><optionset>{0}</optionset></optionsets></importexportxml>", _globalOptionSetName) };
_serviceProxy.Execute(pxReq3);
```

You would detect changes in the SQL and use a query similar to the above to update the option set.

Comment: Thanks, and what would be the best process and trigger for this in CRM, a plugin needs to be triggered by something, or maybe a web service/windows service?. In other words where will this code run and what will initiate the code to run, from a CRM best practice perspective.

Comment: There is no built-in way to have CRM trigger something when changes are made to an external data source. You could create e.g. an external program that runs periodically and polls for changes in you SQL and updates CRM when needed.

Comment: @Henrik This would only update the option set value but not the dependant records, isn't it? It is like when you update an option set value from the UI, but the existing records that were created still retain the old value, which could cause inconsistencies.

Comment: @Jordi It is my understanding that UpdateOptionValueRequest is used for updating the labels of an option set, which is perfectly fine. This will also be reflected in records using the option set. It is not clear to me if OP is trying to just change the labels, or actually wants to delete and insert actual option set values. I agree with you that deleting values would not be advisable, since existing records would still have the deleted value.

Comment: @Henrik, it will be absolutely fine for labels, but the question looked like Papi wanted to update the actual values because they changed from an external system...

Comment: Yeah, in that case I guess we would need some more context from @Papi. If it is only a matter of inserting new values, that would be fine.

Comment: This is for both updates and insert, if the value changes in the source external dab it must update in CRM, and similar if the option set doesn't exist at all, create a new one.